# kafka streams ktable data lost

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a stream application with 2 topic sources. 
one topic is read as KStream and the other one as KTable.
I'm filtering out messages from KStream by performing a join operation on the KTable.
the problem is that after a while (several days) some records from the KTable are disappearing - the join doesn't work as expected.
My KTable topic is defined with compact policy. 
if I'm restarting the kafka stream application thinks work as expected so I guess it is related somehow to RocksDB.
Please advise

Comment: can you find any solution? I'm facing the same issue